# how to insert information in a table from a select statements?

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x

I'm new  working with mysql and I'm trying to insert data into a table from a different table. I've searched and I've found that I need to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

These are the tables' composition:

Credit_request:

```
Fieldname                 DataType

| request_id             | int(10) unsigned      
| customer_id            | int(11)               
| total_credit_value     | int(11)               
| Credit_request_checked | set('yes','no')       
| does_apply             | enum('yes','no')      
| creation_time          | datetime
```

Customers:

```
Fieldname                 DataType

| Customer_id       | int(11) unsigned   
| name              | varchar(70)        
| lastname          | varchar(70)        
| sex               | enum('M','F')      
| personal_id       | varchar(16)        
| phone_number      | varchar(20)        
| email             | varchar(70)        
| birthdate         | date               
| address           | varchar(70)        
| city              | varchar(70)        
| job               | varchar(60)        
| salary            | int(11)            
| registration_date | datetime
```

+-------------------+------------------

but when I try, I get a syntax error. This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO Credit_request(null,'Carlos',custormer_id
 ,default,default,
 default,default,default,default)
 SELECT Customer_id FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name ='Carlos';
```

these defaults values are supposed to be there, I've set them however, I've noticed in order to do this kind of insert I have to reference to each field name but in this case I just want one piece of information from the other table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert only secific columns, you can specify those column names and rest of the columns will be assinged `default` values. Your script would be:

```
INSERT INTO Credit_request(custormer_id)
SELECT Customer_id FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name ='Carlos';
```

This will add one `row` into `Credit_request` table with Carlos's customer_id in customer_id column and `null` in other columns.

Comment: Hey @Darshan Thanks, but actually both tables are different I'm going to make the situation clearer. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @GraphsRodriguez I have updated the answer based on edits in question.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your syntax a little mixed up.  The `INSERT` statement should declare the columns you're inserting into, the `SELECT` statement declares the values.  For columns that have a default, you can omit them.  Nullable columns always default to `NULL` unless otherwise stated.

```
INSERT INTO Credit_request(
    `customer_id`,
    `creation_time`
) SELECT
    `Customer_id`,
    NOW()
FROM `Customers`
WHERE `Customer_name` ='Carlos';
```

Comment: I put in `NOW()` for `creation_time` as you normally set that when inserting a new row in a database table.  You may wish to omit this, or alternately set it in your calling code via a parameter.